# Merge 'storage-full' into 'insufficient-memory'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

After having created the [insufficient-memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory) including tag excerpt and wiki, now used by 10 questions, during re-tagging I discovered the [storage-full](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage-full) on the last question, which is used by 9 questions currently.

Both tags are not really equivalent (`insufficient-memory` directly refers to the "insufficient memory..." error, thus dealing *exclusively* with the devices' *internal storage* -- while `storage-full` is much broader (at least from its name, though ~80% of the questions tagged such seem to explicitly refer to "insufficient memory", and the remaining 20% at least implicitly).

My idea was to merge the two, and convert `storage-full` into a synonym *for now*. So if we really feel we need a separate tag by that name at a later point, it would be easy to retain. At the moment I do not see much sense in a separate broad "storage-full" tag (my, if the card is full one needs to delete something, right? Or buy a larger card).

Please keep `insufficient-memory` as the main tag / merge target, as it already includes a tag wiki with "first aid" as well as a wiki excerpt :)

Comment: Can't find any questions tagged [tag:insufficient-storage] did you mean [tag:insufficient-memory] ? Other than that sounds good, agree that [tag:storage-full] should be the synonym

Comment: Sorry: insufficient-memory... I'll update my Q... Done.

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid the term "memory" when not referring to RAM, since it seems to cause confusion.

Comment: @MatthewRead Go tell Google (or the Android team). The full error message is: `Internal memory space is low` or `insufficient memory available` (app-install via playstore). I fully agree the term "memory" does not apply in this context (as really, internal *storage* is meant). But if the error message speaks of "insufficient memory", what do you think a user will look for in tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes sense to me. These are merged now.